# How to run a macro in excel VBA only on "Save-as" but not on normal "Save"

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I have a form for work that I update and email out daily. I open from one master form ("Passdown Report 3rd Shift"), and save-as individual copies separated by the date ("Passdown Report 3rd Shift 2022-01-19") before I leave each day.

The form is filled with formulas that auto-update based on the day and based off stimuli from the other worksheets in the workbook, so I added a macro to convert all formulas in the range to their values.

I want to run this macro before I save the form as the daily file, but not when I'm simply updating and saving the master file. Is that something I can do?

Comment: Are you saving the code or just as a `.xlsx` file?

Comment: @VBasic2008 So, the `.xlsx` file that I'm saving needs the code and all formulas to stay intact for the master copy, since I start from that point every day. I have a code that converts formulas to their end values and want that code to run only when I'm performing a save-as function. otherwise it would remove all the formulas in my master file, which would defeat the reason I made the formulas in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Run Macro Before Closing a Workbook

- It is expected that you `SaveAs` as the backup.
- Only when closing the backup, the `IF(StrComp...` will note a different file name, and your macro will run and the backup will be saved again before closing.
- It is kind of clumsy, but it should ensure the safety of your original.
- The problem with `BeforeSave` is that you could do `If SaveAsUI = True Then` but you could also accidentally do the `SaveAs` on the original and have it 'destroyed'. I consider it too risky.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private ClosingBackup As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Const sFileName As String = "Passdown Report 3rd Shift.xlsm"
    
    If Not ClosingBackup Then
        With Me
            ' Compare if you're closing the original or the backup.
            If StrComp(.Name, sFileName, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then ' backup
                MyMacro
                ClosingBackup = True
                ' Here it will again call this sub but will exit because
                ' 'ClosingBackup' is set to True ('If Not ClosingBakup Then').
                .Close SaveChanges:=True
            'Else ' ClosingBackup = False i.e. closing the original; do nothing
            End If
        End With
    'Else ' ClosingBackup = True; closing the backup which was saved; do nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong here, please: at `MyMacro` I'm supposed to replace that with `Call ConvertFormulasToValues` , correct? or did I just add an unnecessary complication? Either way, it works beautifully. If I update the file name to reflect a specific date, then it runs my code, if changes are made but the filename stays the same, it doesn't run the code. You sir, are phenomenal. :)

Comment: You are right. It is confusing because the `Call` keyword is considered deprecated so many don't use it anymore i.e. `ConverFormulasToValues` is enough. I'm glad you liked it. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function BeforeSave, on your ThisWorkbook.

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If SaveAsUI then
    'Your code
    end if
End Sub
```

In the microsoft documentation is written on the popup of the SaveAs, this code will be executed and the flag SaveAsUI will be true.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave

*Note: You will need to make it an .xlsm file if you want your macro te be saved...*

Comment: The problem there is that it runs the code regardless of whether I quick-save or save-as. I need those formulas to stay put on my master file, so that when I return to work the following day they can output new values based off the updated stimuli.

Comment: I thought you understand the fact that you will need an if statement, I added it to the answer...

Comment: oh definitely, my apologies for not stating that I'm still definitely n00b status. I would love to learn more completely, but so far I've just been learning through questions I've posed.